# Javascript Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token . for array.length

Tags: javascript, html

I am extremely new to programming and an assignment from class was to create a voting website. I was able to create variables and put them into local storage, as such:

```
var eventName = document.getElementById("eventName").value;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = (eventName);
localStorage.setItem("eventName", eventName)
localStorage.getItem("eventName")
```

Now, we were supposed to include all of this into an array so that we can get multiple eventNames. My teacher is never really clear with his instructions, so this is what I got now:

```
var eventName = [];
var index ;

function submitNewEvent() {

eventName[index] = document.getElementById("eventName").value;
index = index + 1;
var eventNmString = JSON.stringify (eventName);
localStorage.setItem("eventName", JSON.stringify (eventName));
localStorage.getItem("eventName")
array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("eventName"));

array = parse;
var output = "";
for (var i=0, array.length > i; i++){
output += "<p>"+array[i];
}
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = (output);
```

I would really appreciate any help if anyone can explain to me what I did wrong.

Comment: What is `array = parse;` supposed to do? There is no `parse` variable shown, so that should give an error. `var index;` should be `var index = 0;`. Also, why are you using `localStorage` at all? In the code shown the only time you retrieve the value with `.getItem()` is immediately after storing it with `.setItem()`, so that seems pointless - the idea with `localStorage` is to store items now and retrieve them in some later session.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the syntax error (the error message should point to that line as well):

```
for (var i=0, array.length > i; i++){
//          ^
```

The `array.length` expression is not a valid identifier name, like `i` is (in a statement like `var i=0, array=5;` or so). You wanted to use a semicolon there:

```
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
//          ^
```